# reverse keyframe direction of pure css horizontal img slider

Tags: css, css-animations

I am simply trying to reverse the direction my pure css horizontal image slider is sliding. I have tried altering the key frame animation portion with opposite direction, with both `-` position and toggling `left` to `right`, all my attempts do is allow one slide to slide in the correct direction and then just blank white space due to my images `float: left;`

Here is live [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/shiko098/1khoo60p/). *And* here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1khoo60p/15/) of my attempt and how it's rendering (*ie.* *not working. it slides through one image in the correct direction, but not the rest)*

*Also, my code below.*

**Mark-Up:**

```
<div class="slider3">
    <figure>
   <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/a251/i/2007/347/c/8/drunk_santa_by_yakuks.png">
   <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/a251/i/2007/347/c/8/drunk_santa_by_yakuks.png">
   <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/a251/i/2007/347/c/8/drunk_santa_by_yakuks.png">
   <img src="http://img00.deviantart.net/a251/i/2007/347/c/8/drunk_santa_by_yakuks.png">
    </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider3 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider3 figure img {
      width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

.slider3 figure{
    width: 400%;
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    animation: 10s slide infinite;
    -webkit-animation: 10s slide infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% { left:0%; }
    16% { left:0%; }
    33% { left:-100%; }
    49% { left:-100%; }
    66% { left:-200%; }
    82% { left:-200%; }
    100% { left:-300%; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't have to do any modifications other than add `animation-direction: reverse` to the list of rules (or you can set it as a value in the `animation` shorthand). As you'd have guessed, adding this property-value pair would reverse the flow of your animation.

When you place 4 images on a page (with `float: left` and 100% width for each), the 1st image is at 0%, the 2nd is at 100%, 3rd at 200% and 4th at 300%. What your current animation does is - start with the `left: 0%` which means the first image is in view. After sometime the `left` offset is set as -100% and what this means is that the second image which was at 100% on the page will now get displayed (as 100% - 100% = 0% and so it lands in the viewing area). Similarly the 3rd and 4th also gets shown.

Now to reverse the animation, you need the `left` offset to start at -300% so that the fourth image is visible first and then it slides towards the right instead of slide towards the left. **Note:** If you want the first image in the DOM to show up first then change `float:left` to `right` for `.slider3 figure img`.

**With fourth image in DOM appearing first:** (`float: left`)

```css
.slider3 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider3 figure img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
.slider3 figure {
  width: 400%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: 10s slide infinite reverse backwards;
  -webkit-animation: 10s slide infinite reverse backwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  16% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  49% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  82% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  16% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  49% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  82% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider3">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4">
  </figure>
</div>
```

**With first image in DOM appearing first:** (`float: right`)

```css
.slider3 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider3 figure img {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
.slider3 figure {
  width: 400%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: 10s slide infinite reverse backwards;
  -webkit-animation: 10s slide infinite reverse backwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  16% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  49% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  82% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  16% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  49% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  82% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider3">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4">
  </figure>
</div>
```

You'd notice that I have added a `backwards` also to the `animation` short-hand property. This stands for `animation-fill-mode` and it makes the element hold the state as at its last keyframe until the time the animation starts. If this isn't added there will be a snap at the start where the first image will display before immediately changing to 4th (no slide) with `float:left` and vice-versa for `float: right`.

---

Amr Aly's second answer will work (and there are other possible ways too) but there is absolutely no reason to make it so complex.

Comment: @CamC.: Yes both move from left to right. That was my understanding of your requirement. The difference is that with `float: left` the flow will be 4th -> 3rd -> 2nd -> 1st in terms of DOM image order whereas with `float: right` it would be 1st -> 2nd -> 3rd -> 4th. It is just the image flow order that is different between these two and not the direction.

Comment: Just to get it clear @CamC. What is the direction that you are looking for? In your original **live** JSFiddle, the direction I see is right -> left and so I think you want to change it to left -> right. Is that correct?